# how can i use particles.js with react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I use **particles.js**, I need to put `id="particles-js"` on the div of my index.html. But I already have an id attribute (`id="root"`), where I render my App.js. In index.js, which renders the App in `id="root"`, I changed `document.getElementsById('root'))` to `document.getElementsByClassName('root'))`, but it doesn’t work. How can I do this so it works?

in index.html

```
<div id="particles-js" class="root"></div>
```

in App.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, 
  document.getElementsByClassName('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

(I have been importing all files necessary to work… if I put `id="particles-js"` in another div, it works, but I need to use it together with `"root"` to render my App.)

Comment: Couldn't you just put the particles div _inside_ the root div?

Comment: use two `<div>` elements.  `<body><div id="root"></div> <div id="particles-js"></div> </body>`

Comment: @Colin@Dan, tnks :)

Comment: You could use Particle.js but I would use [react-particles-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-particles-js). That's a version of particles.js that will be easier to use in React. You can find a demo of the usage [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/y1qo55xzx).

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName('root') will return an array.
You can try:  `document.getElementsByClassName('root')[0]`.
But you have to promise there is only one className named root.

Comment: i did with `<div id="root"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; height:100vh; top:0; width: 100vw; overflow: auto; z-index: 1"  id="particles-js"></div>`, tnks guys for your help :)